# Does Firebase hosting's CDN support any kind of authentication? (e.g. Edge Auth)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I have a service API running behind Firebase Hosting Rewrite Rule that will benefit from CDN caching as its API response rarely changes, but it will need to be protected from the public. Currently, the server is doing auth check for every request coming in using Firebase Auth's `verifyIdtoken` to see if it should accept incoming request or not.

I was wondering if Firebase Hosting's global CDN supports any kinds of authentication, such that auth check can be done at CDN level. Something similar to [GCP Endpoint Auth](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authentication-method#google_id_token_authentication), or but tailored for Firebase.

As a mitigation for now, the server is setting cache related HTTP headers for requestors to cache the response, however, this is per-user cache, and every new user's request will continue to reach the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All files on Firebase Hosting are accessible by anyone who knows their URL, so should only be used for hosting public files. There is no security mechanism in place.